# Amount of all subsets of size $n$ in a set with $e$ elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How do I find the amount of subsets that have *n* elements in a set with *e* elements?

For example, if you had a set with 5 elements, and wanted all subsets with 3 elements, you would have 10 subsets.

Comment: These being: (1,2,3), (1,2,4), (1,2,5), (1,3,4), (1,3,5), (1,4,5), (2,3,4), (2,4,5), (3,4,5), and (2,3,5) (thanks for pointing that out).

Comment: You skipped $(2,3,5)$.

Comment: As Berci noticed, your first answer (10) was right as you will find $\binom{5}{3}=10$.

Comment: See [Combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) : "a k-combination of a set S is a subset of k distinct elements of S. If the set has n elements, the number of k-combinations is equal to the binomial coefficient."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for are [binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient). In your case, the quantity you want is $\binom{e}{n}$.

Using induction, you will find that $\binom{e}{n}=\frac{e!}{n!(e-n)!}$.

If you did not have previous knowledge of binomial coefficients, here is how you might find those values:

- you choose a first element (you have $e$ choices), $e-1$ elements remain
- you choose a second element (you have $e-1$ choices), $e-2$ remain
- you go on until you have chosen $n$ elements, you had $e\times (e-1) \times .... \times (e-n+1) = \frac{e!}{(e-n)!}$ ways of doing that
- what you now have is an **ordered** collection of elements, but you only want a subset of your initial set, that is, an **unordered** collection. To switch between the two, you must find how many ways you have to order the $n$ elements you extracted. That number is $n!$.

So in the end, you indeed have $\frac{e!}{n!(e-n)!}$ ways of extracting your subset.

Answer (score 0):

The number of sets of size $n$ we can construct from a set of size $e$ is $\binom{e}{n}$ where
$$ \binom{e}{n} = \frac{e!}{n!(e - n)!} = \frac{e \times (e-1) \times \cdots \times (e-n+1)}{n \times (n-1) \times \cdots \times 2 \times 1}$$
One way to prove this is to first consider choosing ordered lists of $n$ distinct elements from $e$. There are $e$ ways to choose the first element, then $e - 1$ ways to choose the second element, then $e - 2$ ways to choose the second element, and so on. Therefore there are $e \times (e - 1) \times \cdots \times (e - n + 1) = \frac{e!}{(e - n)!}$ ways to choose a list of $n$ distinct elements from a set of size $e$.

Then to get the number of sets, note every set of $n$ elements can be ordered in $n!$ different ways. So by counting ordered lists of distinct elements we overcount by a factor of $n!$, hence we divide by $n!$ to compensate. This gives the formula at the start.